# Rails helper method return NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have this code in `User#index` view:

```
<%= User.find_each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

which returns the user names:

```
user1 user2 user3 ...
```

Then I move this code to the `UserHelper`:

```
module UserHelper
  def get_users
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.name
    end
  end
end
```

And call it from the `User#index` view with:

```
<%= get_users %>
```

The problem is that this is not returning any user. If I use `<%= get_users.class %>` it outputs `NilClass`. Why is the helper method not returning the user names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper method implicitly returns the result of calling `find_each`, which is different than returning a collection of user names.

Think of it like running `5.times { |n| puts n }`: what's the value of that? Not "0 1 2 3 4", but "5", because `times` returns what it was called on, not what's run in its block.

Your original code, by the way, returns the exact same thing--you are relying on a side effect inside the `find_each` block, i.e., appending `user.name` to the response.

If you want to return a collection of the users' names you'd want to `map`/etc. and grab each user's name. Or, IIRC, you can do a find and a pluck so you only get back the users' names instead of all user fields.

Comment: using  `map` solved the problem. I changed the helper to: `User.find_each.map { |u| u.name }` and the view to: `<%= get_users.join(' ') %>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below also,

```
  <%= User.all.map(&:name).join(' ') %>
```